Is it possible to make a variable non-zero in LP, but either positive or negative?
Fore pure (not integer) LP, I was wondering whether it is possible to encode the fact that a variable $x$ can be either positive or negative, but not zero. I was thinking of the possibilities which expressing $x$ as the difference of $2$ non-negative variables could afford, as well as playing around with the objective function.
It is sole curiosity which drives me to ask this question. My algorithms textbook says that the constraint that variables be non-negative in standard LP can be gotten around by expressing a variable as the difference of $2$ variables, so I was wondering if the constraint that the scope of the variables has to include $0$ can be gotten around.

No, as the set $\mathbb{R}\setminus{0}$ is not convex and the feasible set of any LP is convex.

However, you can still decide efficiently if a variable can be made non-zero by perturbating a feasible solution, see an answer I gave https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4979704/966819
